# does the name Rigg have anything to do with being "rigged?" or is it just a land area?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, expressions, abbreviations, colloquialisms

I know of a friend with the surname of Rigg.  She identifies this as being
referred to land and ridges.  does it have anything to do with something   being "rigged?"

Comment: The study of the origins of surnames is a very specialised field. Perhaps the best site on the web, deling with this is [*The Guild of One Name Studies*](http://one-name.org/Results). Unfortunately the name *Rigg* has not yet been registered with them for research. But if you are sufficiently interested, you might consider working through them. I seriously doubt it has anything to do with something *being rigged*, which sounds to me like relatively recent slang. Often the genuine origins of surnames bear little relation to similarly-sounding modern words.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the study of the origins of surnames is a very specialised field. And I don't think it's one that ELU is normally concerned with.

Comment: My guess would be that Rigg is a trade name (like the names "taylor", "walker", "smith") associated with someone who supplied or worked with rigging (nautical).

Comment: Surnames tend to be derived from three sources:  Locations, trades, and the "first names" of ancestors.  *Rigg* could refer to a location (possibly a notable ridge in the area), it could refer to a trade (perhaps a sail maker), or it could, eg, be derived from a word that means "blessed person", being the given name of an ancestor.

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous sites about the origin of Rigg as a surname which, as the following, suggest that it derives from Old English terms. A  connection between the surname and the term rigged appears unlikely because the latter is much more recent in origin as shown below:

***[Rigg](http://www.surnamedb.com/Surname/Rigg):***

> - ***This is a very old English topographical surname for someone who lived on or by a "ridge" or "back".***
> - ***The derivation is from the Olde English pre 7th Century word "hrycg", ridge, in Middle English, "rigge,*** although in some areas of concentrated Scandinavian settlement the name may come from either the Olde Norse "hryggr" or the Old Swedish "rygg".

(www.surnamedb.com)

***[Rig](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=rig) (v.)***:

> - late 15c., originally nautical, "to fit with sails," probably from a Scandinavian source.  ***Slang meaning "to pre-arrange or tamper with results" is attested from 1938, perhaps a different word, from rig (n.) "a trick, swindle, scheme" (1775),***  earlier "sport, banter, ridicule" (1725), of unknown origin.

(Etymonline)